# inline stylesheet to cascading stylesheet

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

i have developed a web apps (using mvc4 ,css)having more than 18 projects.
but there is a problem i have used inline style in that project but now i want to seperate styles into  external css style sheet.it will take more time to give class to each and replace the style from .cshtml page to css page and give link of css.
please help me and suggest me better option

```
On .cshtm page
<img src="~/Content/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"/>
```

To

```
<img src="~/Content/loading.gif" class="styleNew"/>



 on .css page

.styleNew
{
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Better option: only use inline styles ***if you absolutely need to***. Now you've got lots of unnecessary and tricky work to do.

Comment: thanks ,but is it not possible with dreamviewer?

Comment: You'll have to manually go through and add `classes`, and then move that `CSS` to the external `.css` file, there isn't really an automated way of doing this - because your elements don't have classes added to them already. Read this - **[Dreamweaver - Convert inline CSS to a CSS rule](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS8BC8A54F-60BC-40bd-A368-50A405C51350a.html)** but it's still going to be a manual process.

Comment: thanks nick i know it actually another guy developed this project and got the job to do this stuff ..... :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to automate converting inline css to external css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546960/tool-to-automate-converting-inline-css-to-external-css)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone already answered this for you - see the first response, there's an online tool to extract inline css and distill it into classes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546960/tool-to-automate-converting-inline-css-to-external-css

Comment: http://inlinecssextractor.com/home.html this one is good but basically its not creating class its recog. the elements by id but i am looking for class based tool